# How to delegate ada to several staking pools using only one wallet?

Tags: wallet, staking

At the moment if you want to delegate different amount of ada to more than one staking pool you should have two or more wallets. Is there a way to delegate a portion of the coins to one staking pool and another portion to other staking pools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nami wallet you can create "extra accounts" to delegate to other pools. You do have to keep into account that other wallets will not show these "extra accounts".

Answer (score 7):

In Yoroi, it is possible to delegate to multiple pools using a single wallet, but not in Daedalus. To delegate to multiple pools in Daedalus, you will need to create separate wallets. The stake associated with each wallet can then be delegated to a specific stake pool.

It is worth noting that multiple-pool delegation using a single wallet will not be supported on the mainnet.

**Source** : https://cardano.org/stake-pool-delegation/ (At the bottom, "Can i delegate to multiple stake pools ?")

Comment: Interesting, but this is only valid for the Yoroi browser extension? Can't find this option in the Android App.

Comment: What does it mean "multiple-pool delegation using a single wallet will not be supported on the mainnet"?